# Fundamental theorem of algebra using Liouville

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I was asked to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra using Liouville's theorem in complex analysis.

Here is my approach:

Suppose $f(z)$ does not have a root.
Then I divide into two cases:
(1) $|f(z)|>0$ and (2)$|f(z)|=0$
For case (1) there exists some real $r$ such that $|f(z)|<r<0$ , thus take $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ and then apply Liouville's theorem to prove that $ f$ is constant as it is entire and bounded.
But what for case(2)?

Comment: Case (2) does not occur, as you assume, that $f$ has no root.

Comment: why? can you explain?

Comment: If for a complex number $a$, you have$|a|=0$, it follows immediately, that $a$ is zero.

Comment: This is a standard application of Liouville's theorem. See any textbook.

Comment: So is this proof a valid one?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard application of Liouville's theorem. A proof can be found in any textbook.

Unfortunately, your proof is not correct.

1. If $f$ does not have a root, then $\lvert f(z) \rvert > 0$ for all $z$. The case $\lvert f(z) \rvert = 0$ for *some* $z$ cannot occur.
2. It is impossible that $\lvert f(z) \rvert < r < 0$. Perhaps you mean $\lvert f(z) \rvert > r > 0 $ for all $z$? To *prove* this, you have to show that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \to \infty$ as $\lvert z \rvert \to \infty$ (which is true because $f$ is a polynomial).